# numpy.vectorise() signature potentially causes scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard() dimension issue

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, scipy-spatial

I'm a `numpy` baby and am looking at using `numpy.vectorise()` to compute a distance matrix.  I think that a key part of this is the `signature` param, but when I run the code below I get an error:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import jaccard

#find jaccard dissimilarities for a constant 1 row * m columns array vs each array in an n rows * m columns nested array, outputting a 1 row * n columns array of dissimilarities   
vectorised_compute_jac = np.vectorize(jaccard, signature = '(m),(n,m)->(n)')

array_list = [[1, 2, 3], #arrA
              [2, 3, 4], #arrB
              [4, 5, 6]] #arrC

distance_matrix = np.array([])
for target_array in array_list:
    print (target_array)
    print (array_list)
    #row should be an array of jac distances between target_array and each array in array_list
    row = vectorised_compute_jac(target_array , array_list)
    print (row, '\n\n') 
    #np.vectorise() functions return an array of objects of type specified by otype param, based on docs
    np.append(distance_matrix, row)
```

Output + Error:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\u03132tk\.spyder-py3\ModuleMapper\untitled1.py", line 21, in <module>
    row = vectorised_compute_jac(array, array_list)

  File "C:\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2163, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)

  File "C:\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2237, in _vectorize_call
    res = self._vectorize_call_with_signature(func, args)

  File "C:\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2277, in _vectorize_call_with_signature
    results = func(*(arg[index] for arg in args))

  File "C:\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py", line 893, in jaccard
    v = _validate_vector(v)

  File "C:\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py", line 340, in _validate_vector
    raise ValueError("Input vector should be 1-D.")

ValueError: Input vector should be 1-D.
```

What I would like, with square brackets indicating numpy arrays not lists, based on array output types discussed in comments above:

```
  #arrA    #arrB   #arrC
[[JD(AA), JD(AB), JD(AC)],   #arrA
 [JD(BA), JD(BB), JD(BC)],   #arrB
 [JD(CA), JD(CB), JD(CC)]]   #arrC
```

Can someone advise how the signature param works and whether thats causing my woes?  I suspect it's due to the (n, m) in my signature as it's the only multi-dimensional thing, hence the question :(

Cheers!
Tim

Comment: Hi, you're aware that `np.vectorize` is not really vectorized, right? Then if you're fine with explicit loops, there is `[jaccard(arr_1, arr_2) for arr_1 in array_list for arr_2 in array_list]` which you can reshape later.

Comment: As I understand, this is a symmetric metric; so you can save time by doing only the ~half of it. You can also skip the trivial `d(x, x) = 0` ones, i.e., when the arrays are the same. The number of `jaccard` calls then reduces to *n(n-1)/2* from *n^2*.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply!  Yea I saw it was meant to be basically a for loop but I was hoping it was doing some behind the scenes magic to be a bit quicker :( I'd quite like to learn to vectorise more and i swear a vectorised solution should be fairly doable haha, ill keep thinking!

Comment: The `signature` mode of `np.vectorize` is even slower than the basic scalar mode. `np.vectorize` is NOT the numpy vectorization that gives it so much speed and power.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to run your code as is, but then saw that you were misusing `np.append`.  So I'll skip your iteration, and try to recreate the calculation with straight forward list comprehensions.

It looks like `jaccard` takes 2 1d arrays, and returns a scalar, and you apparently want to calculate it for all pairs of your list of arrays.

```
In [5]: arr = np.array(array_list)
In [6]: [jaccard(arr[0],b) for b in arr]
Out[6]: [0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
In [7]: [[jaccard(a,b) for b in arr] for a in arr]
Out[7]: [[0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0]]
In [9]: np.array(_)
Out[9]: 
array([[0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0.]])
```

With symmetry and 0s it should be possible to cut down on the `jaccard` calls with a more selective iteration.  But I'll leave that for others.

With your `signature`, you are telling `vectorize` to pass a 1d and a 2d array to the `jaccard`, and to expect back a 1d.  That's not right.

This is, I think the correct use of `vectorize`:

```
In [12]: vectorised_compute_jac = np.vectorize(jaccard, signature = '(m),(m)->()
    ...: ')
In [13]: vectorised_compute_jac(arr[None,:,:],arr[:,None,:])
Out[13]: 
array([[0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0.]])
```

Compare its time against the nested comprehension:

```
In [14]: timeit vectorised_compute_jac(arr[None,:,:],arr[:,None,:])
384 µs ± 5.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [15]: timeit np.array([[jaccard(a,b) for b in arr] for a in arr])
203 µs ± 204 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

In [15], it's the `jaccard` calls that dominate the time, not the iteration mechanism.  So taking advantage of the symmetry will worth it.

```
In [17]: timeit jaccard(arr[0],arr[1])
21.2 µs ± 79.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```